# Как добавить слово в словарь .txt?

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, у меня идет поиск анаграмм в словаре, есть некоторое кол-во слов в этом словаре. Когда программа не находит это слово выводится текст "Слово не было найдено в словаре" , как сделать так , когда данное слово не было найдено, его можно было добавить, нажав на клавишу "Добавить" - button1_Click? 
*Ниже представлен код анаграммы, если это необходимо.*

```
private void FindWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"1.txt"))
        {
            dict.Add(line, string.Concat(line.ToLower().OrderBy(c => c))); // Каждое слово из файла приводится к нижнему регистру и сортируется (по буквам) в алфавитном порядке
        }
        string word = string.Concat(textBox1.Text.ToLower().OrderBy(c => c));
        var valStrings = dict.Where(w => w.Value == word).Select(x => x.Key);
        richTextBox1.Lines = valStrings.ToArray();

        if (valStrings == null || !valStrings.Any()) // проверка слов
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "Слово не было найдено в словаре.";
        }
    }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Добавить куда??

Comment: добавить в словарь, когда ищу слово - анаграмму, данного слова может не быть в словаре, и мне нужно его добавить

Comment: Вот это `dict.Add(…)` в вашем коде добавляет элементы в словарь.

Comment: нет, новые слова не появляются

Comment: Вы храните все слова в файле. В него и добавляйте новое слово. А собственно словарь  — локальная переменная. Что бы вы со словарем не делали, если не измените файл, то при последующем вызове метода `FindWord_Click` новое слово не появится. Имхо не стоит каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку читать заново файл и создавать словарь. Не лучше ли сделать словарь полем формы, создавать его один раз при инициализации формы, изменять его в процессе взаимодействия пользователя с формой и записывать слова из словаря в файл перед закрытием формы?